# Why can't I use the same cfqueryparam in two locations in the same query when using CFScript?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong, but it seems that you can not use a cfqueryparam more than once in a single query if you write it in CFScript.

This behavior is not consistent with CFML. I just re-wrote a similar query from CFML to CFScript and I'm getting the following error: `cfsqlparam 'id' is not defined`

```
local.query = new Query();
local.query.setSql("
    SELECT id
    FROM myTable
    WHERE myTable.id = :id OR myTable.parentId = :id
");
local.query.addParam(name="id", cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER", value=arguments.id, maxlength=10);
local.query.execute().getResult();
```

If I take out the `OR myTable.parentId = :id` it works perfectly well. Do I have to create a param for every location I intend to use one?

Comment: Have you tried adding a second `
local.query.addParam(name="id", cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER", value=arguments.id, maxlength=10);`? If so, what happens? Believe the cfscript parser call `query.addParam()` only does a replacement on the first match it finds.

Comment: I like the cut of your jib, this could make a good feature request.

Comment: @orangepips, doing that the query works as expected. It turns out I need to add a query param for every location. A query param can not be used in more than one place.

Comment: It seems that this is fixed in 9.0.2, and also fixed in the hotfixes for 9.0.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it was a CFQuery you would have one cfqueryparam for each value:

```
where myTable.id = <cfqueryparam... value="#arguments.id#" />
    or myTable.parentid = <cfqueryparam ... value="#arguments.id#" />
```

so I'm guessing you need to do the same thing in script:

```
local.query.setSql("
    SELECT id
    FROM myTable
    WHERE myTable.id = :id OR myTable.parentId = :pid "); 
local.query.addParam(name="id", cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER",value=arguments.id,maxlength=10); 
local.query.addParam(name="pid",cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER",value=arguments.id,maxlength=10);
```

As for the question "why can't the one addParam address both placeholders" I'm guessing it comes down to how the query is parsed by ColdFusion - because you specify two param placeholders the parser probably expects to find two params defined.